# Static variables persisting across sessions in WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, session

I have a WCF service with sessions required

```
   [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required) ]
```

and some static fields.  I thought that by having sessions, the static fields would remain the same for each session, but have new instances for different sessions.  However, what I'm seeing when I have two different clients use the service is that when one client changes a field's value, this change also affects the other client.  Is this normal behavior for having different sessions?  Or do you think my service might not even be creating different sessions?

I'm using netTCPbinding.

Answer (score 10):

Static variables are shared across the entire process, hence the behavior you see.  But if you set the service's [instance context mode to per-session](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86007/3-ways-to-do-WCF-instance-management-Per-call-Per), then that service instance will be created per session, along with its (non-static) variables.  So here `somevar` is unique to the session:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)] 
public class Service : IService
{
    private string sessionVariable;         // separate for each session

    private static string globalVariable;   // shared across all sessions
}
```

Comment: But what if the service is instantiated more than once in the same client?  Would somevar get reset or would it have the same value for any instances across the session?

Comment: @Orch that's a good question -- I believe it would be the latter.  Session is based on a cookie or a token in the URL, which should stay the same even if a new client is instantiated.  In other words, WCF is smart enough to only instantiate one service instance.

Comment: @Orch actually, here it says that in WCF the client is responsible for initiating and closing the sessions.  So ultimately the client will decide when the session ends. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Static field is global for the life of the application. So different clients see the same static variable. If you want 'static variable' for each client then you would have to store it somehere in session state of that user (I don't know WCF well so I don't know what that means exactly in the context of WCF)

Answer (score 3):

Scope of a static variable is Application Domain, this is because your actual Type (class from which instances are created) is loaded once in an application domain, and so are all its static variables and methods associated to it. So even if you have multiple instances or single instance of a service, they will share the static variable.